# How do make the file have a name that the user inputs

Tags: c++, fstream, mkdir

Alright after the program makes a folder I would liek to put a file in that folder but I want the file to be of a name the user would put in so how would I do that because as I have it set up now all it does is makes a file by he name of Exampleuser input and putting "/two" just makes a file by the name of two.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string newFolder = "Example";
string test ;
string two;


int main()
{

    _mkdir((newFolder.c_str()));

    getline(cin,test);
    two = test;


    fstream inout;
    inout.open(newFolder + two,ios::out);
    inout << " This is a test";
    inout.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the Operating System?

Comment: You may need a separator between the folder name and the file name.  For example, on Linux it would be: `new_folder + "/" + two`.

Comment: Alright thanks the "\\" worked for me because im on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The older standards of c++ require you pass a `const char*` parameter to the `std::fstream::open()` method. You can just write

```
inout.open(std::string(newFolder + "/" + two).c_str(),ios::out);
```

or for windows file system

```
inout.open(std::string(newFolder + "\\" + two).c_str(),ios::out);
```

Comment: Why do you have to construct a temporary string? Just do: `(newFolder + "/" + two).c_str()`

Comment: @0x499602D2 I wasn't aware that it can be done with brackets `()` solely, THX. Though as it is, it might give a better clue what's going on for the OP.

Comment: In my experience, you can use `/` in calls to the Win API (which the C++ implementation will boil down to eventually on Windows) and it accepts it as a path separator. Not sure if this is universally guaranteed or not.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Might depend on the WinOS version. I think the latter is _guaranteed_ to work there.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
.
.
string filename;
cin >> filename;
string path; // the path to newfolder = "Example"
path += filename; //append filename to the path, which in  your case you should append "\\" between path and filename as well.

ofstream ofs(path); // create the file
.
.
ofs.close();
```

Comment: Which (essential) information does your "answer" add (code only answers aren't the wanted style here)? Explain your code changes and their advantages over present answers to the question please.

Comment: You are right about explaining the solution, however I think the person who asked the question or needs such solution, will understand how this works! A new answer should not necessarily add something to an existing post, it can be an alternative way to a problem that may be more clear to some people.

Comment: _'... it can be an alternative way ...'_ Yes of course, but not with code only. As I've mentioned, add some explanation.

Comment: I think the code is clear, I added a bit as comment.